# How to add new button in Laravel nova?

Tags: laravel-nova

How can I customize my Laravel nova by adding new button near "Edit" and "Delete" buttons?
[Laravel nova buttons by default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/959iu.png)

Answer (score 1):

For anybody else wondering how to do this, I just figured it out and wrote a quick tip on my blog: https://www.codepicky.com/extend-laravel-nova-components/

The gist of it is that you need to replace one of Nova's components and essentially inject your own component into it.

So, find a component that's on the spot you want to add your component, and replace it with your own, then reference the original component inside your new component, to bring it back.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways but it also depends a bit what you want to do.
Do you want to run an action against a set of resources then you should create a new action with artisan nova:action . https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/actions/defining-actions.html

But there are many more reasons such as predefined filters or links. The best is probably to scout https://novapackages.com unless it exists as a built in feature.